# Ftp and database over android?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, ftp

I'm thinking of developing a small app in Android this summer between classes,  mostly for learning purposes.  I learn best by attempting things Iv found. Now I have an idea of what I want to do,  however I have not offically learned much on a few of the subjects I think will be required,  mostly just done some googling around. As such I wanted to confirm or reevaluate some of my thoughts on how this application might work....

The idea of how this will be used is that it's basically an app that you can upload and download files with....

I figure I can build a server off an old laptop at home to do this with,  probably ubuntu desktop... I don't know that I am ready for the server version yet

As far as the server is concerned I was thinking a simple Java program to handle FTP, and a database to manage the file system by storing class paths?

So listening to a socket for a request to query the database for a specific file,

It receives this request,
generates and send the query...(I don't know if I am getting ahead of my self, but maybe the query is generated client side as a string value?) anyways then the database is queried,  receiving a class path to the file.

The program uses the class path to locate the file and send the application the file(over a different port?)

Also how would I know where to send it as well.. Would I'd send the IP of the phone with the query?)

Also,  since I am using a computer on a network behind a firewall and all,  I would have to forward my ports to the router correct?

Is this anything close to right?

Feel free to edit or suggest any phrasing or formatting of this questions,  and I may very well be asking all the wrong questions. 
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FTP is an insecure transfer protocol and pretty outdated, plus you have to use the apache.commons.net lib in your android project to get a decent ftp client working which, I felt, was a pain in the A.

Don't waste your time, with FTP. Consider an HTTPS REST-like solution with:

- Firebase
- Java / MySQL(ODBC)
- C#(ASP.NET) / TSQL

and learn how to set up SSL for your server in the process.

Comment: Could you reference some sources that I might use to read up on these?

Comment: Also,  ODBC is a library for my sql?  Like JDBC for postures?

Comment: You can use JDBC it uses appropriate drivers to convert to ODBC. There a heaps of tutorials on the net. But if you want to get startet look for a simple Tutorial on how set up a file Server who accepts incomming files per put or post request then set up your databse and once you got your infrastructure running start to develop your app. Personally I recommend Node.js/Firebase because it is easy to get started with and there are heaps of tutorials on the net/youtube. You would want to get the general idea how everything works the implementation should always be interchangable.